# AWS CLI command query ebs volume-id based on EC tag name

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Need some help to fix this query

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=UST1TWASDEVP02A" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.[VolumeId]"
```

This keeps given me this output :

```
[
    [
        [
            [
                "vol-0eb27ed4482aa6b72"
            ],
            [
                "vol-0a8a5716d4abb92cc"
            ],
            [
                "vol-0adb47a85b3541697"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I only need to extract the second value.

I was able to use jq to get the result

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=UST1TWASDEVP02A" | jq -r .Reservations[0].Instances[0].BlockDeviceMappings[1].Ebs.VolumeId
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to extract the second value, you could use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=UST1TWASDEVP02A" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[1].Ebs.[VolumeId]" --output text
```

The difference is using `BlockDeviceMappings[1]`, which will the second `BlockDeviceMappings` entry for each Reservation+Instance combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following commnad to print the second volumeID:

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=UST1TWASDEVP02A"  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].[Ebs.VolumeId]" --output text | sed -n '2p'